# mongodb: python return field if exists

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am trying to query over a collection to check if a field exists:

currently:

```
sample_doc = list(sample_collec.find({'id': 11}, {'toyo_id': 10, '_id': 0}))
if sample_doc:
    print(sample_doc[0]['toyo_id'])
```

is there a one-liner, shorter and faster way to return `toyo_id` instead of returning the whole list and then getting it by index?

Comment: What is the problem are you facing?

Comment: @Gibbs on a huge data, there are multiple statements like these, which are taking very long time.

Comment: Time is not related to number if statements. Do you have index on those fields?

Comment: If you just want a single document, try findOne.

Comment: Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/ with findOne